# CodeIgniter file validation is showing even if file is selected

Tags: codeigniter

I m in big trouble, new to CI. Not finding my mistake I m doing.
I m just trying to upload file which needs required validation, but if I select the file it still shows required validation error message. rest validations are working fine for me. When I do not select the file it shows the error 'Please select file.' which is correct but the same error shows even after I select the file. I don't understand, what I m missing exactly.
Here is my code.

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('list_name', 'List Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name_product', 'Product Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cost_of_list', 'Cost of list','numeric|required');
              $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_file', 'Document', 'callback_file_selected_test');
            // Validation for Excel file upload
              /* if (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
                   $this->form_validation->set_rules('file', 'Document', 'required');
                } */

               if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

                   echo json_encode(array( 'status' => false, 'msg' => validation_errors())); 
                  }
```

file_selected_test function

```
function file_selected_test(){

        $this->form_validation->set_message('file_selected_test', 'Please select file.');
        if (empty($_FILES['user_file']['tmp_name'])) {
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
    }
```

Following code is View

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">List Information</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body form">
        <div id="validation-error" style="color:red;"></div>

       <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" name="product_id"/>
          <div class="form-body">
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-md-3"> <label class="control-label">List Name</label></div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="list_name" placeholder="List Name" class="form-control" type="text" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3"><label class="control-label ">Product Name</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
             <select class="form-control" name="name_product" placeholder="Product Name"  class="form-control" id="name_product"  >
<option disabled selected value> -- Select An Option -- </option>          
           <?php 

            foreach($products as $product)
            { 
              echo '<option value="'.$product->product_id.'">'.$product->name_product.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-3"><label class="control-label">Description</label></div>
              <div class="col-md-9"> 
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment" name="description" ></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-3"><label class="control-label">Cost of List</label></div>
              <div class="col-md-9"> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="cost_of_list" ></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3"><label class="control-label">Select File</label></div>

            <div class="col-md-9"> 
<input id="input-2" name="user_file" type="file" class="file"  >
                </div>
                </div>  
 <div class="form-group" id="companyCount" style="display:none;">
 <div class="col-md-3"><label class="control-label">No of companies</label></div>

              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="no_of_companies" placeholder="No of companies" class="form-control" type="text" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>

 <div class="form-group" id="contactsCount" style="display:none;">
             <div class="col-md-3"><label class="control-label">No of Contacts</label></div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="no_of_contacts" placeholder="No of Contacts" class="form-control" type="text" >
              </div>
            </div>          
            <div id="search_rolebase"  style="display:none;">
<div class="form-group" >
             <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center"><label class="control-label">Search criteria for Rolebase</label></div>
</div>             
             <div class="form-group" id="">

                <div class="col-md-3"><label class="control-label">Titles</label></div>


              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="titles" placeholder="Titles" class="form-control" type="text" >
              </div>
              </div>
               <div class="form-group" id="">
               <div class="col-md-3"><label class="control-label">Country</label></div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="country" placeholder="Country" class="form-control" type="text" >
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div id="search_accountbase"  style="display:none;">
             <div class="form-group" >
             <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center">
             <label class="control-label">Search criteria for Account Base</label></div></div>             
             <div class="form-group" id="">

                <div class="col-md-3"><label class="control-label">Region</label></div>


              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="region" placeholder="Region" class="form-control" type="text" >
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Not working even updated to codeignitor function 
Same results are showing in upload function, here is the code

```
 $file_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../uploads/files/');

                $config['upload_path']          = $file_path;
                $config['allowed_types']        = '*';
               // $config['max_size']             = 100;
               // $config['max_width']            = 1024;
               //  $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->upload->initialize($config);     

               if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
               {
                    echo json_encode(array( 'status' => false, 'msg' => $this->upload->display_errors()));
                }
```

It is showing error 'You did not select a file to upload.' but when I code separately for the only upload, it's working fine.

Comment: Why not use CI file uploading library,? It has it's own validation.

Comment: I tried but the same error.

Comment: what about different path  `$config['upload_path']  =  './uploads/files';` also check if directory exists and has writing permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your validation Code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('list_name', 'List Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name_product', 'Product Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cost_of_list', 'Cost of list','numeric|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_file', 'Document', 'callback_file_selected_test');
```

#### Try This Way:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('list_name', 'List Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name_product', 'Product Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cost_of_list', 'Cost of list','numeric|required');

if (empty($_FILES['user_file']['name']))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_file', 'Document', 'required');
}
```

Try this condition:

```
if($_FILES['userfile']['error'] != 4)
{
 return false;
}
```

`$_FILES['userfile']['error'] != 4` is for file required to upload.

Comment: I have updated the answer can you please try that and get back with the result. Thanks

Comment: Hi, again get an here. Please check the screenshot here http://img.ctrlv.in/img/17/09/07/59b0d11c36df7.png

Answer (score 0):

try to change the tmp_name to name cause it can be NULL while passing values [as given in this link](http://www.codingforums.com/php/165293-$_files[userfile][tmp_name]-empty.html)

change code to

function file_selected_test(){

```
    $this->form_validation->set_message('file_selected_test', 'Please select file.');
    if (empty($_FILES['user_file']['name'])) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
}
```

try this way too